# The symbol packaged downloaded from MS site

Tags: windows, windbg, symbols

I just downloaded the symbol package for WIN7 RTM but in my windbg it still find the symbol information for RegQueryValueEx().

From the windbg information it said some of the OS dll symbol is not provided in the pdb file, but how can I know which ones are not provided and which one does?

Specifically the symbol I am searching for is RegQueryValueEx();

Thanks.
Bin

Comment: To be clear the RegQueryValueEx is contained in advapi32.dll, when I am using the dbh.exe to see the symbols in the pdb file it do contain the symbol information for the RegQueryValueEx.
Does this mean the symbol is not correct?

Comment: d:\Symbols\advapi32.pdb\6AEFDCFF7F2A429B8532CD2BFDDF85D12>dbh advapi32.pdb
advapi32 [1000000]: enum RegCloseKey

 index            address     name
     6            1020920 :   RegCloseKey

advapi32 [1000000]: verbose on

verbose mode on.

advapi32 [1000000]: enum RegCloseKey

 index            address     name
     6            1020920 :   RegCloseKey

advapi32 [1000000]: addr 1020920

RegCloseKey
   name : RegCloseKey
   addr :  1020920
   size : 0
  flags : 0
   type : 0
modbase :  1000000
  value :        0
    reg : 0
  scope : SymTagNull (0)
    tag : SymTagPublicSymbol (a)
  index : 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can watch your loaded modules and corresponding symbols using the `lm` command. However, since WinDbg doesn't load symbols until they are needed, you can do a `.reload /f` to force load of all symbols.

If the output from `lm` says (pdb symbols) for a given module, you have the correct public symbols for that module.

Comment: Thanks! 
The lm listed (pdb symbols) but when I am using "dt RegQueryValueEx" it still can't get the symbol.

Comment: Isn't dt used for dumping types? I would think that RegQueryValueEx is a method and not a type.